# How to stop getting __webpack_hmr

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

After webpack build, the application is still trying to get __webpack_hmr

How to stop it?

[my project](https://faofao931013.github.io/test/index/#/number/i)

Comment: Closing the browser tab would stop it. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the following from your `webpack` `entries` config.

1. `webpack-hot-middleware/client`
2. `react-hot-loader/patch`

This will stop triggering the `_hmr_` requests.

Comment: I have solved it.thanks.